# ubuntu 14.04 Dual boot with windows 10 , "+" button is not active

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

During installing ubuntu , when I choose something else and my partitions appear , also free space which I made appear . 
the "+" button is not active , so I can`t make a swap area or root partition >
What should I do ?! Help

Answer (score -1):

Can you post an image of your drive as it appears in the "Something else" screen?

Is this a clean drive or do you have another operating system already installed on this drive?

Any further details you can provide would be helpful (i.e. is this an internal or external drive, what version of Ubuntu are you using, etc).